# Download data in text format

Tags: pyarrow, huggingface-datasets

How do I download the data from hugging face website?

For e.g. I tried to download an example dataset...

```
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset("oscar", "unshuffled_deduplicated_mr")
```

> Reusing dataset oscar
> (/root/.cache/huggingface/datasets/oscar/unshuffled_deduplicated_mr/1.0.0/84838bd49d2295f62008383b05620571535451d84545037bb94d6f3501651df2)

There are 3 files saved in that folder...

```
total 1.4G
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.1K Jul 21 10:03 LICENSE
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5.8K Jul 21 10:03 dataset_info.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.4G Jul 21 10:03 oscar-train.arrow
```

But I need a text file and not .arrow file. Is it possible using hugging face or should I use some other way to download the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the data to csv this way:

```
import pyarrow.csv as csv

csv.write_csv(dataset.data['train'].table, "data.csv")
```

But this particular data set contains a lot of commas `,` and carriage returns `\n` which will need to be escaped in order for the csv file to be readable.